# How to prove the sequence $\frac n{2n+\sin^2(n)}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

[Here is how far I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a86SQ.png)

I think I made a mistake by assuming it converges to a half? This is my first time proving using the definition so my understanding is quite bad. I have to prove using definition.

Comment: function=$\frac{1}{2+\frac{sin^2(n)}{n}}\to \frac{1}{2}$.  Seems easy enough.

Comment: You do not really need the definition. Just factor the denominator by $n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you write

\begin{equation}
\frac{n}{2n + sin^{2}(2n)} = \frac{n}{2n(1+\frac{sin^{2}(2n)}{2n})} = \frac{1}{2\left(1 + \frac{sin^{2}(2n)}{2n}\right)}
\end{equation}
it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $\dfrac{n}{2n+1} \le \dfrac{n}{2n+\sin^2n}\le \dfrac{1}{2}$. Using sandwich lemma we conclude the limit equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.